# Len returns 'Type Mismatch' error vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that checks two columns to see if a string contains a number, and if it does it colors the entire row Red.
The code worked fine, until I got a data set this morning that returned the error 13 'Type Mismatch'. 
Can you help me please with causation why would this appear?
Thank You in advance.

```
Dim u As Long, j As Long, LR As Long, charCount As Long 
LR = Range("M" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For u = 1 To LR
    charCount = Len(Range("M" & u).Value)
    For j = 1 To CharCount
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Range("M" & u).Value, j, u)) Or IsNumeric(Mid(Range("N" & u).Value, j, u)) Then
            Range("M" & u).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
            GoTo BailOuty
        End If
    Next j
BailOuty:
Next u
```

Comment: Do you know the value it gets stuck on and could you post it? When the error appears go into debug mode and check the value of `u` to find the row number.  May also be better to replace `GoTo BailOuty` with `Exit For`.

Comment: I'd bet you have an error value in there.

Comment: Yes, I checked but it's pretty strange, when I filter the column a "#NAME?" appears in the filter list but when I select the specific value to filter it doesn't show anything...

Comment: @Rory Thank you, so that is what's causing the error, I had some names that had "=- " before them, generating the #NAME? error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Len()` only works for string arguments.

For example, `Len(123)` won't work because 123 is a number, not a string (but `Len("123")` will work just fine).

The `Range`'s `Value` is probably of a number datatype, not a string in that case, but there's an easy way to fix it: Just append an empty string to the value and VBA will convert the entire thing to a string:

```
cellValue = Range("M" & u).Value & ""
charCount = Len(cellValue)
```

Please note: you can still use the `isNumeric()` formula, even if the argument is a string:

```
IsNumeric(Mid(cellValue, j, u))
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. Whilst `Len` will error (a compile error, not run-time) if you pass a number *literal* to it, it will work with a number *variable*, but it will return the size of the data type (eg 4 for `Long`) rather than the number of digits. Weirdly, either `VBA.Len` or `Strings.Len` works with literal number values and returns the number of characters.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Good to know - I'll leave my answer with your comment up for reference.